# How to store and fill in with test data for exploratory testing

Tags: testing, automated-tests, software-quality, exploratory

I am doing lot of exploratory testing, for which I have to fill in random information manually for email, password, first name, middle name, last name, address and ph#. Which takes considerable amount of time. So I would like to ask is there any chrome extension or application that saves data from www.fakenamegenerator.com and refill the saved data when needed.

I tried different chrome extensions like Form Filler, Fake Data, Bug magnet and all. Those didnt help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use google chrome Auto-fill setting :- Setting-> Show Advance Setting -> Manage Auto-fill settings..

Comment: This helps when we use same data (Which is already saved) every time. Which needs a lot of manual efforts while we need to fill 100 forms with some sample data. I found a chrome extension **Fill all inputs**, which is really helpful in such case.